Post Processing Bloom effects performance
I want to create Post Processing effects with Unity Post Processing Stack. I have found this post from this website  Unity post processing Bloom lags on mobile, but it had no answers. I have exactly the same problem: If I add bloom shader, the performance on android build drops from stable 60fps to like 30 fps. But different to the question I linked, the performance in the editor is just fine.
I don't know how to fix this, any help is appreciated!
Update:
I will add hierachy and stuff later, because I am not at home now, but this is a screenshot of the game:


Post processing effects are somewhat antagonistic to the tile-based rendering mobile chips use to conserve memory bandwidth. The whole image needs to get written out to shared memory (slow) then read back in (slow) to perform the blur. So while you might be able to make incremental improvements, you should expect this will always be more expensive on mobile than on desktop. In your game scenes, can you approximate the bloom effects with shaders on bright objects or halo geometry instead?

I don't know how I could do that with shaders, as all YT tutorials I found, even though they used shader graph for some parts of their project, all of them used post processing to make bloom.

Want to show us a sample of the scene you want to bloom? We may be able to suggest ways to tweak it for better efficiency.

Can update the question later this day to include hierachy and stuff, but I will update it now to add a photo of the build.

What model are you testing on?

What do you mean by model?

This effect looks like one you could achieve by pre-baking the bloom effect into a texture with fuzzy gradient edges, then drawing that texture card additively over the ball's position. That would be way more efficient on mobile than a full bloom pass. The enemies in Lovers in a Dangerous Spacetime use this "baked bloom" approach.
